# Cannot change parameters in all treeview tables in same time - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have several treeview tables.

After some moment I need to apply some property **to all tables**.
All tables are combined in dictionary, for example:

```
all_trees = {1: some_tree, 2: one_more_tree, 3: another_tree}
```

When the moment appears I need to make this type of operation to change one property in all tables:

```
for key in all_trees.keys():
    tree = all_trees[key]
    tree.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: new_property(event, tree))
```

New property makes appearing text 'hello' after right click mouse to the row in table.
After executing this operation **only the last** table has the new property.

What's the problem? Why this property is not applied to all tables?
P.S: i need to make my project using python2.7, so all my code is written using old version of python

Below is a full code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import Treeview, Frame
from Tkinter import Menu, LEFT, NO, YES


data_for_tables = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'} 
list_of_tables = [1, 2, 3]

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def make_tree(frame):
    """creating Treeview table"""

    tree = Treeview(frame)
    tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
    tree.heading("#0", text="")
    tree.column("#0", minwidth=0, width=5, stretch=NO)
    tree.heading("one", text="Port")
    tree.column("one", minwidth=0, width=30, stretch=NO)
    tree.column("two", minwidth=0, width=60, stretch=NO)
    tree.heading("three", text="State")
    tree.column("three", minwidth=0, width=60, stretch=YES)
    tree['height'] = 3
    tree.pack(side=LEFT)
    return tree

def insert_value(info, tree):
    """Inserting values to Treeview table"""

    for key in info.keys():
        tree.insert("", "end", values=(str(key), info[key], "<><><>"))

def new_property(event, tree):
    """after right ckick mouse appears text 'hello' in console"""

    row_id = tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if row_id:
        print('hello')


global all_trees
for num in list_of_tables:
    all_trees = {num: make_tree(frame)}
    for key in all_trees.keys():
        tree = all_trees[key]
        insert_value(data_for_tables, tree)

for key in all_trees.keys():
    tree = all_trees[key]
    tree.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: new_property(event, tree))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: After doing `tree = all_trees.keys()`, have you examined `tree` to see if it's what you think it is? I'm guessing it's not what you think it is.

Comment: The second posted code does not match with that in the full code.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

```py
global all_trees   # <-- not necessary
for num in list_of_tables:
    all_trees = {num: make_tree(frame)} # <-- reset all_trees
    # below for loop is not necessary
    for key in all_trees.keys():
        tree = all_trees[key]
        insert_value(data_for_tables, tree)
# at here, all_trees has only the last item created in the above for loop

for key in all_trees.keys():
    tree = all_trees[key]
    tree.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: new_property(event, tree))
    #                                                          ^
    # 'tree' used inside lambda will be always the last 'tree' after the for loop
    # actually this argument is not necessary
```

Below is sample how to fix the above issues:

```py
def new_property(event):
    tree = event.widget
    row_id = tree.identify_row(event.y)
    if row_id:
        print('hello', tree, row_id)

all_trees = {num: make_tree(frame) for num in list_of_tables}
for tree in all_trees.values():
    insert_value(data_for_tables, tree)
    tree.bind("<Button-3>", new_property)
```